# Bootstrap 4/CSS: Why does the bullet point overlap the input?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, html-lists

I have an unordered list. Each list item wraps an input. I am using Bootstrap.

Here is my document:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="check-item">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter something">
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the `li` bullet point to be rendered outside of the input. Everything renders as I expect it to in Chrome. In Safari the bullet is not rendered initially. However, the bullet point *does* appear when the input is double-clicked, but it appears overlapping the input.

This problem does not occur without bootstrap.

I have tried adding:

```
<style>
  ul {
    list-style-position: outside;
  }
</style>
```

But the problem remains. Does anyone know why this is happening in Chrome but not Safari? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: is the problem still present with unstyled `<ul class="list-unstyled">` ?. _"Remove the default list-style and left margin on list items (immediate children only)."_ I mean I don't know if it will help, but worth a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it has to do with the default display property of input elements differing between browsers. It appears fixed when style="display:inline;" or style="display:inline-block;" is added to the input.